# meteor-with-angular tutorial: dependenciesproblem

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I am playing with this tutorial: http://angularjs.meteor.com/tutorial/step_05   which is for learning angular on top of meteor.
When separating the views and routing, I have this code on the app.js: (on the right in the console is my problem...)

code and exception from chrome console
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGusb.png

inner Code exception: "[$injector:nomod] Module 'ngLocale' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."

packages file: 
meteor-platform
autopublish
insecure
urigo:angular
urigo:angular-ui-router

Comment: Have you tried comparing your code with the prepared solution?  https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-angular-socially/tree/step_05      also please try to provide with more code, maybe through MeteorPad

Answer (score 0):

We just released a new version - 0.6.0-alpha which removes the need of including the urigo:angular-ui-router packages.

Please look again into the same step of the tutorial and try it with the new version.

Please let me know if it works for you.